# AppleScript: Open URL in specific tab (Google Chrome)

Tags: applescript, google-chrome, tabs

I can no longer open a URL in a specific tab using AppleScript.
I tried the following code without success:

```
set URL of tab 1 to "https://"
```

and

```
set myLink to "https://"
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    tell front window to make new tab 1 with properties {URL:myLink}
end tell
```

neither of which perform the desired action.

**Question**
What do I need to change in the code in order to be able to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me on the latest version of macOS Sierra

```
set myLink to "https://google.com/"

tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell its window 1
        set theTabs to count of tabs -- how mmany open tabs
        set URL of tab 1 to myLink -- insert desired tab
        --set URL of (make new tab) to myLink
    end tell
end tell
```